# Return lambda Node < Node

Tags: python, heap, nodes, priority-queue

I'm receiving this compiler error when putting a Node onto a min-priority queue.

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Node' and 'Node'
```

Here is where it fails

```
from queue import PriorityQueue

def huffman(text):
    A = frequency(text) # returns a dictionary {(frequency, character),...}
    q = PriorityQueue()
    heap = build_min_heap(A) # builds min heap 
    while heap:
        temp = pop_heap(heap) # format (frequency, character)
---->   q.put(Node(temp[1],temp[0],None,None))
        # Node(character, frequency, left child, right child)

def min_heapify(A, i, key=lambda a: a):
    lefti = 2 * i + 1
    righti = 2 * i + 2
    heap_size = len(A)
--->if lefti < heap_size and key(A[lefti]) < key(A[i]):

    /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/queue.py in put(self, item, block, timeout)
    141                             raise Full
    142                         self.not_full.wait(remaining)
--> 143             self._put(item)
    144             self.unfinished_tasks += 1
    145             self.not_empty.notify()

    /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/queue.py in _put(self, item)
    225 
    226     def _put(self, item):
--> 227         heappush(self.queue, item)
    228 
    229     def _get(self):
```

I found a workaround by adding an "lt" function to the Node class.

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    return self.frequency < other.frequency
```

However, is there another way to fix this using lambda expressions or modifying the min-priority queue in some way?

Maybe a key function perhaps? I understand what key(value) is doing but I don't know how would I interpret it as a Node. I tried something like the following, but it didn't work.

```
def key(item):
    if instanceof(item, Node):
        return item.frequency
```

Also to note that the heap functions also process int values and other types. This is way later in the code where I'm passing Nodes to the heap/queue.

Note: The Node is sorted by frequency.

Here is my Node class

```
class Node():

    def __init__(self, character=None, frequency=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.character = character
        self.frequency = frequency
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def isLeaf(self):
        return self.left is None and self.right is None

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.frequency < other.frequency

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Node({}, {}, {}, {})'.format(self.character,
                                         self.frequency,
                                         self.left, self.right)

def min_heapify(A, i, key=lambda a: a):
    lefti = 2 * i + 1
    righti = 2 * i + 2
    heap_size = len(A)
    if lefti < heap_size and key(A[lefti]) < key(A[i]):
        smallesti = lefti
    else:
        smallesti = i
    if righti < heap_size and key(A[righti]) < key(A[smallesti]):
        smallesti = righti
    if smallesti != i:
        A[i], A[smallesti] = A[smallesti], A[i]
        min_heapify(A, smallesti, key)

def build_min_heap(A, key=lambda a: a):
    for i in range(len(A) // 2 - 1, -1, -1):
        swaps = min_heapify(A, i, key)
    return A
```

A final word, I understand that "lt" works in the Node class, but I'm trying to figure out another solution that doesn't involve modifying the Node class because other sites have comments that say to use a lambda expression (e.g. The key function should return the frequency stored in the argument to key, which should be a Node.; do we need to write the key function? Yes. It can be a simple lambda expression.) but they are vague in how to accomplish that.

Comment: That's not a *workaround*, that's literally "adding support for '<' between instances of 'Node' and 'Node'".  Why do you want to do it any other way (especially using lambda expressions)?

Comment: Since a priority queue needs to understand sorting order of the objects in it, it seems like supporting the order in the node class itself is the most sensible thing to do.

Comment: Why are you using both `build_min_heap` *and* `queue.PriorityQueue`? What even is `build_min_heap`? It kind of sounds like `build_min_heap` already handles node ordering the way you want.

Comment: Sorry, I added the min heap functions.  I thought it wasn't relevant but your comment convinced me it was.